# TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'class'

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

I am stuck here. Typescript keeps complaining that:

> TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private name
>   'class' Student

test.ts

```
export default  function MODULETOEXPORT(GreetingIntroTxt:string) {

    class Student {
        name: string;

        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        greet() {
            return `"${GreetingIntroTxt}, " + this.greeting`;
        }
    }

    class Teacher {
        name: string;

        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        greet() {
            return `"${GreetingIntroTxt}, " + this.greeting`;
        }
    }
    class Professor {
        name: string;

        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        greet() {
            return `"${GreetingIntroTxt}, " + this.greeting`;
        }
    }
    return {Professor, Student, Teacher}
}
```

Although I copy paste the exact same code on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), I get no error and it compiles perfectly.

To reproduce:

usage.ts

```
console.log('hello world app')
import module from './test';
const moduleES = module('Holla')
const moduleFR = module('Salut')
const moduleEN = module('Hello')

const greeterESStudent = new moduleES.Student("world");
console.log(greeterESStudent.greet())

const greeterFRStudent = new moduleES.Student("world");
console.log(greeterFRStudent.greet())


const greeterESTeacher= new moduleFR.Teacher("world");
console.log(greeterESTeacher.greet())

const greeterFRTeacher= new moduleFR.Student("world");
console.log(greeterFRTeacher.greet())
```

Comment: Sounds like a scope visibility problem in the return type.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: maybe you should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685129/typescript-blocks-node-module-factory-pattern-error-ts4060) .

Comment: [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA287PQOwGMYBLCfOAWQHkARAVQBkBRAFWuYA0AFagJVYAKAOJRgwUvgDmASXwwoEViBgAuAM4KS0gJRwA3gChDcU3EKZU69XADKMdEnkGTZt-lQBbYKriao2lIA3MZuboTk-ujE0IIe3r7+gXpGYWlwMAAWJOoAdPHAcAC8cAUh6XAAvqHpUmISgimuFaZiDlAUAAYARAAk+qLikrLyisowlQA0cN1wANQZ2Xl1Q4Gd5enVbtXN5pbWcKzAqISZwFAuFQWJWtIhu+GRCtEwsdd+t1JNLWZZOfleQolMoPMw7CorBrfH5wNroDpwHr9QYSQJyBRKFRTGbzRb-SHDdag0xbMG7CxWGzcRTIYDWaCXdLvJJ3GppCL4KIxKBxQE3AK6Rk-P55ArFUqAjZpcG1eowRpClpwhFIgZytGjTETaazBYi3IEtZSsKkkm7ZUUfTUiC0+lQab2RzAeTTI4nM5QaqVIA) the ts playground link you wanted to share?

Answer (score -1):

You should make the private member public. There is no way around this.

A similar will be thrown if you use a non-exported type from another module.